# In python Panel, how to show a matplotlib plot in a panel.Tabs view?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, holoviz, holoviz-panel

The Python Panel library recommends using Bokeh for plotting, but some statistical figures are lacking from the Bokeh package. I want to use matplotlib (or maybe seaborn) to create figures that I can place in panel.Tabs.

For example, the following code works but uses Bokeh instead of matplotlib:

```
import panel as pn
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p1 = figure(width=400, height=400, name="Line 1")
p1.line([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

p2 = figure(width=400, height=400, name='Line 2')
p2.line([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0])

pn.Tabs(p1, p2)
```

This (correctly) shows:

[image]

However, every attempt I made to show an image from matplotlib failed. Something like `p1 = plt.plot(df['wage'])` simply does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Holoviz Panel uses the concept of panes to render figures (plotly figures, bokeh figures, matplotlib figures)... For example, to render a matplotlib figure you have to use `pn.pane.Matplotlib` ([here is its documentation](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/panes/Matplotlib.html)).

Note that it requires the figure to be created with `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead of the more traditional `plt.figure`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

fig1 = Figure()
ax1 = fig1.subplots()
ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])

fig2 = Figure()
ax2 = fig2.subplots()
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0])

pane1 = pn.pane.Matplotlib(fig1, dpi=96)
pane2 = pn.pane.Matplotlib(fig2, dpi=96)
pn.Tabs(("title 1", pane1), ("title 2", pane2))
```